# Notepad++ virtual left padding after gutter?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to add some sort of padding or "virtual spacing" along the left edge of a file in Notepad++?

I don't want the spacing to actually be in the file, just a bit of virtual separation from the gutter.

Is this possible?

[image: desired padding circled in yellow]

Answer (score 2):

You can't add the margin by default by this a plugin called you can be made possible the same.
A Plugin can make help to achieve the same name `LuaScript`

Steps:

1. Download plugin using notpadd++ plugin admin
2. Install and setup value for `editor.MarginLeft` using `plugins->LuaScript->edit startup script`
3. Restart on notepadd++ and enjoy

Check snapshots more clear view.

[image: plugin name]

[image: settings]

[image: Value settings snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a space reserved for the folding feature, similar to what you want, but you need to set the language of the file (for php and most of the languages it does do and for normal text it doesn't).

You can set this feature in

> Settings>Preferences>Editing  Folder Margin Style

I can't post images because my reputation, but I hope it can be helpful

Comment: Add link to images then we will put it on your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to make it look like there is a margin on the left by going to:
**Settings** => **Style Configurator**, and then under Style: => Fold margin, I made the Foreground colour and the Background colour the same color.
At least it made it look more like I wanted it to look (easier to read).

I'm using Notepad++ v7.8.4 (32bit)

It was the best I could do for myself, hope it helps.

Comment: lol, I don't even use NP++ for programming anymore, but kudos for responding on a tumbleweed thread.