# How do I add padding to top of file in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I would like to add a space such as the height of one line, so that the first line is a little lower than the top of the file.

How can I add this feature?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1551640/545165

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do that?

Comment: To see the top row easier with smaller text

Answer (score -1):

Add a new empty line at the beginning of file:

Find what: `^\A(.*)$`

Replace with: `\r \1`

Select *Regular Expression*

Comment: 1) You should reread the question. 2) `^\A` doesn't make sense. 3) `\r` is used only in old Mac.

Comment: \A  Match only the first line of the file.
I tested the options without the \A and it still works.   the \r matches carriage return characters